# Cyclic dependencies not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two projects inside my solution, Core and Infrastructure. In Core I have my Services and in Infrastructure I have SignalR. I somehow need to access my Services from SignalR and SignalR from Services.

- In case of ChatHub, on new message, I'll call Service to add new entry in DB.
- In case of Order is updated, I'll call OrderHub to send event back to client.

For second case to be clearer: I'm using Stripe, and listening for Stripe Webhooks (inside services) and sending update to client about their order while they are on order page.

How can I make this without causing circular dependency?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the constructors to your question where the circular dependency is? Are you using dependency injection? Which one are you using if any?

Comment: @garethb I'm using constructor injection

Comment: I was going down the path of using your DI container service locator to get a reference to the dependency instead of using the constructor to inject it. For .net core something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-injection-with-fromservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to do this is to add an extra abstraction layer, and have the classes use the interfaces for each service.

Now, for the SignalR part of your question, the first thing I think of is define an `Event` on your service and subscribe to it on the Hub.
This way you decouple the Service from the Hub, as the Service does not need to know about the Hub, and will just fire the event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to do it with Events, but having troubles. I'm using constructor injection and when I debug, I see that it adds listeners and when it's time to invoke the event from the service, it's null. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the lifetime of each object?

Comment: Hmm they are scoped

Comment: That sounds like the problem. If you want to have that kind of subscriptions I believe you want to have the Service as a singleton

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have made another service that I have added as Singleton, as I couldn't current one. Thank you once again!

Comment: What I ended up doing is I have moved Service interfaces to a separated project and used them in the Hub where needed, and injected IHubContext in my Service where I needed to send event to SignalR clients. Problem with Event and Singleton is that I couldn't use Service without initializing Db using create scope in the Hub, which just doubled events sent each time. I feel more comfortable with my final approach but I want to thank you once again as you have pointed me in new direction I wasn't thinking of :)

Comment: That's great! Glad you figured it out!